# Working out prior distribution given prior density

Tags: probability, statistics

This the prior given

π(θ) ∝ 1/(θ(1 − θ))

and I need to work out the posterior distribution but I can't figure out how. I worked out the likelihood to be 10*θ^2*(1-θ)^3, but can't figure out how to cancel them down to fully give me the posterior.

Comment: Please write out the full problem and show your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply (something proportional to) the (improper) prior density by the likelihood, you get something proportional to the posterior density, here $10\theta^1(1-\theta)^2$

But you want it to integrate to $1$, presumably over the interval $[0,1]$, The integral is $\int\limits_0^1 10\theta^1(1-\theta)^2\, d\theta = \frac{10}{12}$ so dividing by this gives a posterior density of $$12 \theta(1-\theta)^2$$ on $[0,1]$, a Beta distribution.